# How do you edit a file in the node_modules folder on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

Locally I needed to fix a bug in an npm package, but when uploading the server to heroku, the npm gets reinstalled and my fix is of course gone. Is there a way to edit the file inside the node_modules folder inside heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `patch-package` package for that
https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `patch-package` by itself solves the problem you encountered. The problem is described in this issue logged in the `patch-package` project: https://github.com/ds300/patch-package/issues/130

It says:

> When using Heroku's Node buildpack, by default the following will happen during the build and startup process:
>
> 1. install all dependencies (including `devDependencies`) with `yarn --production="false"`
> 2. run build step
> 3. prune dev dependencies with `yarn --production="true"`
> 4. run the app
>
> However, at step 3 when the dev dependencies are pruned, the buildpack also specifies the `--ignore-scripts` flag when calling `yarn` (since v119). This means [your post-install script] will not run, because the postinstall/prepare scripts will not be ran. In turn, this means when the app runs, Node modules will not be patched (!).

As per the 'Skip Pruning' section of [this Heroku doc](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning), you can set environment variables to skip pruning. Alternatively, you might be able to (re-)apply your patch in the "heroku-postbuild" step.